# script without `crossorigin` will not expose its error?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, cross-domain

### Here is my files

```
crossorigintest
├── 1.html
└── 1.js
```

and the file content is

#### 1.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        window.onerror = function () {
            console.log('onerror', arguments)
        }
        window.addEventListener('error', function () {
            console.log('addEventListenerError', arguments)
        }, true)
        window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', function (event) {
            console.log('unhandledrejection', arguments)
            event.preventDefault();
        });

    </script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8081/1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

#### 1.js

```js
console.log(11);
(function(){
    console.log(22);
    throw new Error('oops')
})()
```

### start http-server

```sh
cd crossorigintest
npx http-server
npx http-server --cors
```

then the files will be proxyed at `http://localhost:8080` and `http://localhost:8081`

### open browser

with `http://localhost:8080/1.html`

### see the result

[image]

Actually the error is exposed outside to the html,so what does the spec mean?
`https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-crossorigin`

> The crossorigin attribute is a CORS settings attribute. For classic scripts, it controls
> whether error information will be exposed, when the script is obtained from other origins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my test, it's up to my chrome's privacy settings.
When the third option is selected, the spec works.
[image]